# What are the registers to be saved in 8086 assembly coding while an assembly function is called

Tags: assembly, x86-16

While i call an assembly function from another function what registers should i save(8086)

for eg: in arm assembly coding i'm saving r4-r12 registers.

Should i also save BX, CX, DX, SI, DI @Multimedia Mike

Comment: Really 8086? That's antique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[e]ax, [e]cx, [e]dx are caller saved registers, [e]bx, [e]si, [e]di, [e]bp are callee saved registers, meaning that any function can trash eax, ecx and edx.

It's also customary to return "structs" or 32-bit values in dx:ax pair in 8086-land.

[Calling conventions according to wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions)

Answer (score 4):

You should save whichever registers you intend to use, and do so within the function, not from outside the function. It's customary in 8086-land to save the BP register and then use it to reference parameters pushed on the stack, restoring the BP register on exit. Also, if you need to return a value, you use the AX register by convention.

**Update**: In response to your updated question, you should save those registers if your ASM function uses them. If you don't want to manage this manually, you can always use pusha/popa which will push/pop all the x86 registers.